# An integral involving Bessel functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

Does anyone have suggestions for how to approach this integral that I came across in a project? Can one apply identities to make it doable analytically or using Mathematica? I tried but couldn't get very far. Thanks a lot!

$$\int_0^{\infty}dx\ x^2 e^{-\epsilon x}J_{n-1}(ix)J_{n+1}(ix)\frac{Y_n(ix)}{J_n(ix)}.$$

Here $J_n$ and $Y_n$ are Bessel functions of the first and second kind respectively.

Comment: Quick note, you can rewrite Bessel functions with argument $ix$ in terms of the opposite kind (first to second or second to first kind). That will help simplify your expressions a bit. As for evaluating, you're going to have a pretty tough time I think. There is not a lot known about integrals of products of three Bessel functions or more.

Comment: The $\frac{Y_n(ix)}{J_n(ix)}$ can be simplified [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.18) using Bessel argument functions